# JQuery Ajax Error {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"OK"}

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I try to get the cities according to the country which is passed as parameter and sent via ajax. But for some countries I can get  cities and update my form with these cities, for against for other I have this error

`{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"OK"}`

When I look in logs for those countries that returns me an error I have the names of the cities retrieved from the database.

I do not understand why this error.
 how can I fix it?

Please find below my code

**Model**

```
 function get_ville_depart($country = null){
        $this->db->select('NUMVILLEDEPART, NOMVILLEDEPART')->from('villedepart');
        $this->db->join('pays','pays.NUMPAYS=villedepart.numpays');
        $this->db->where('pays.NUMPAYS', $country);
        $this->db->order_by("NOMVILLEDEPART","asc");
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $cities = array();

        if($query->result()){
            foreach ($query->result() as $city) {
                $cities[$city->NUMVILLEDEPART] = $city->NOMVILLEDEPART;
            }
            return $cities;
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
 function get_ville_depart($country){
        foreach($this->ville_model->get_ville_depart($country) as $ville){
            log_message('debug',json_encode($ville));
        }
        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
        echo json_encode($this->ville_model->get_ville_depart($country));
    }
```

**View**

```
$('#paysdepart').on("change",function(){
                $("#villedepart > option").remove();
                var country_id = $('#paysdepart').val();
                var base_url="<?= site_url('annonce');?>";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: base_url+"/get_ville_depart/"+country_id,
                    dataType:'json',
                    success: function(cities)
                    {
                        if(!jQuery.isEmptyObject(cities))
                        {
                            $("#ifnotvilledepartindatabase").hide();
                            $("#dynamicvilledepart").show();
                            $.each(cities,function(NUMVILLEDEPART,NOMVILLEDEPART)
                            {
                                var opt = $('<option />');
                                opt.val(NUMVILLEDEPART);
                                opt.text(NOMVILLEDEPART);
                                $('#villedepart').append(opt);
                            });
                        }else
                        {
                            $("#dynamicvilledepart").hide();
                            $("#ifnotvilledepartindatabase").show()
                        }
                    },
                    error:function(error)
                    {
                        alert("Error "+JSON.stringify(error));
                        $("#dynamicvilledepart").hide();
                        $("#ifnotvilledepartindatabase").show()
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: In controller remove `foreach` loop that *may* print out message. Other than that, I see nowhere that you format that kind of json

Comment: Also try to use urlencode () method to encode city names and use it after decoding in js to avoid special character problems in city names.

Comment: @Justinas foreach is for looking via log  the values of cities which are return by model. I think With "echo json_encode()" in my controller I format and return cities as json

Comment: Find in your code where it says `statusText`, confirm, that this code is executed when you get that JSON and than show code.

Comment: check this link http://www.justinball.com/2013/02/25/jqxhr-returning-readystate-0-and-status-0/

Answer (score 0):

Error in those country which does not have any City.

```
    if($query->result()){
        foreach ($query->result() as $city) {
            $cities[$city->NUMVILLEDEPART] = $city->NOMVILLEDEPART;
        }
        return $cities;
    }else{
        return new stdClass; /* Only this line have to change */
    }
```

Use direct URL to see the error for the particuler Country ID. 
I have tested in local everything if fine .

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems fine to me, but here my guess about your code :
==> MAKE SURE THE COUNTRY ID IS NEVER EQUAL TO NULL
1 - in your Model, change this,

```
if($query->result()){
    foreach ($query->result() as $city) {
    $cities[$city->NUMVILLEDEPART] = $city->NOMVILLEDEPART;
    return $cities;
}
else{
    return FALSE;
}
```

to this :

```
if($result = $query->result_array())
    $cities = array_column($result, 'NOMVILLEDEPART', 'NUMVILLEDEPART');

return $cities;
```

2 - in your Controller, change this :

```
function get_ville_depart($country){
    foreach($this->ville_model->get_ville_depart($country) as $ville){
        log_message('debug',json_encode($ville));
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($this->ville_model->get_ville_depart($country));
}
```

to this :

```
function get_ville_depart($country){
    $countries = $this->ville_model->get_ville_depart($country);
        return $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')
                    ->set_output(json_encode($countries));
}
```

3 - In your View, Change this :

```
var country_id = $('#paysdepart').val();
```

to this :

```
var country_id = $(this).val();
```

Note : you can access directly to this page "http://{mywebsite}/get_ville_depart/{country_id}"
with {country_id} equal to the country ID you have a problem with, and check if everything's OK before using the Ajax Query.